# Can I have a static link-local ipv6 address with dhcp for the other ipv6 settings? (netctl or systemd)

Tags: ipv6, systemd

I'm using systemd (specifically netctl) and trying to create a network profile which has dhcp or stateless auto config IPv6 but also allows me to specify a static link-local IPv6 address. I've read the documentation and looked over the examples, and tried every sensible combination of options, and I just can't come up with a working configuration. The error I typically see is that I don't have a link-local address, which is particularly ironic since I'm trying to manually specify said address.

My broken config files usually look something like this:

```
IP6=dhcp-noaddr  #or stateless, or dhcp
Address6=fe80::1/64
```

I would write out all of the IPv6 settings, except that I don't have a static IPv6 address assigned to me. I don't want to change all the config settings on every computer each time my ISP changes my address. How can I make a static link-local address while also using DHCP/stateless autoconfig? The answer doesn't have to be netctl, but I am stuck with systemd.

(And yes, I'm aware that link-local addresses are ~~useless~~ not portable in linux. At this point I just want to know the answer.)

Comment: Note that systemd has nothing to do with this at all; you might be confusing netctl with systemd-networkd. (And link-local addresses _aren't_ useless).

Comment: Okay, I fixed the title. link-local is somewhat broken in linux because you always have to specify the interface, and interface names have become hardware dependent. Thus any config files where you specify a link-local address has to be changed when the hardware changes.

Comment: Link-local addresses aren't useless; in fact they're [mandatory](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.8). You will always have one if IPv6 is working properly. And a link-local address will often be your default gateway.

Comment: Other types of IPv6 addresses don't require users to specify an interface when using the address. This is a special shortcoming of link-local addresses in linux. And yes, mandatory things can be useless. To be fair, let's just say they're "not portable" in linux.

Comment: The name itself, "link-local", already implies non-portable; it's the same across all operating systems and to a certain extent even in IPv4. Doesn't make them useless – I've had at least three different uses for them over the past few months. Imagine that.

Comment: If you choose link-local over site-local addresses, you've made a mistake. Link-local addresses are entirely worse than site-local. Also, non-portable means it's different on different hardware with the same software, and it's also different with different OSes for that matter.

Comment: That's not a shortcoming of link-local addresses; it's inherent to the design. "Link-local" means it's only valid on that particular network connection. It is limited to that interface and is not routable. This is also not a limitation of Linux; the same is true of every operating system that supports IPv6.

Comment: Other OSes, at least OSX, is able to figure out which interface you want. Typically this isn't hard; only one interface is even connected. Linux doesn't try. Thus you must always specify the interface name, which isn't as predictable as eth0 anymore. Move an OS image from one machine to another, and any Link local IPs you've saved will break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the address manually in a post-up command:

```
ExecUpPost="
    ip addr add fe80::1/64 dev $Interface scope local;
"
```

Comment: Good find, I had overlooked ExecUpPost in the documentation. In case this is unclear to future readers, ExecUpPost goes in the netctl profile file alongside the other options.